# I'm trying to make a component, which works as background image, be shown only if another component is rendered

Tags: angular

In my current scenario when I apply this background component in the html file it is shown on the page even if theres no element to be shown. All I'd like to know is how can I see the background only if there's a video being shown on that div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you add your code and elaborate on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div [ngStyle]="{backgroundImage: yourCondition ? 'url(yourUrl)' : null}">
  content
</div>
```